# A passive way of the Redis Expires

Tags: redis

I have a question while I'm studying about `Redis` with docs.
Here is the description in official Redis document about expiration :
https://redis.io/commands/expire

```
Specifically this is what Redis does 10 times per second:
1. Test 20 random keys from the set of keys with an associated expire.
2. Delete all the keys found expired.
3. If more than 25% of keys were expired, start again from step 1.
```

After I read this, I have a question about `25% of keys` above.
What is the `keys` meaning in `25% of keys` exactly? 
The `keys` are the all of keys in Redis? or `20 random keys` in description above?

I think the `keys` are looks like the all of keys in Redis. 
I couldn't find any description about this in document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a key in Redis does not have a time to live (ttl) set. The 20 random keys in this algorithm are sampled from the set of all keys where an explicit ttl has been set. If more than 5 of the keys in this sample have expired then it's likely that the portion of expired keys in Redis is high, and so the algorithm repeats to try to drive the portion of expired keys down below the threshold.

It's important also to note that keys that have lived beyond their ttl will be expired automatically on access (meaning if the user tries to request them).  So a heuristic algorithm like this simply needs to ensure that Redis doesn't pile up a bunch of expired keys, while making sure that Redis is not spending too many resources cleaning up expired keys.

See the source code:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/expire.c

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. Thanks again :)